# Control camera movement with mouse in bge?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, 3d-mouse

Is there a way I could make the mouse look actuator use translation values instead of rotation?

The idea is to move the camera left and right instead of just rotating it.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably edit the python script found here

http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/Game_Engine/MouseLook/blend/MouseLook249.txt

follow the tutorial
http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/Game_Engine/MouseLook/MouseLook_First_3.html

just change this part:

```
# set the values
act_LeftRight.dRot = [ 0.0, 0.0, leftRight]
act_LeftRight.useLocalDRot = False  

act_UpDown.dRot = [ upDown, 0.0, 0.0]
act_UpDown.useLocalDRot = True
```

to :

```
# set the values
act_LeftRight.dLoc = [ 0.0, 0.0, leftRight]
act_LeftRight.useLocalDLoc = False  

act_UpDown.dLoc = [ upDown, 0.0, 0.0]
act_UpDown.useLocalDLoc = True
```

Hope it works.